# B-Tree implementation on C++ has a memory leak?

Tags: c++, data-structures, b-tree

I have this B-Tree implementation, which I'm testing using search() and insert(). Testing is basically this:

```
void function(){
    BTree b16(16);
    // do lots of inserts and searchs on b16
}
for(many_times){
    function();
}
```

If I understand correctly, after each iteration of function(), b16 should get destroyed. However, after ~250 iterations, I get a bad_alloc error, which means I have a memory leak.

Is there a problem with the destructors? Here's the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int uint;

class BNode{
    private:
        uint *keys;
        int B;
        BNode **C;
        int n;
        bool leaf;

    public:
        BNode(int temp, bool bool_leaf);
        ~BNode();
        void insertNonFull(uint k);
        void splitChild(int i, BNode *y);
        void traverse();
        BNode *search(uint k);
        friend class BTree;
};

class BTree{
    private:
        BNode *root;
        int B;
    public:
        BTree(int temp);
        ~BTree();
        BNode *search(uint k);
        int search_bool(uint k);
        void insert(uint k);
};

BNode::BNode(int t1, bool leaf1) {
    B = t1;
    leaf = leaf1;
    keys = new uint[2*B - 1];
    C = new BNode *[2*B];
    n = 0;
}

BNode::~BNode(){
    delete[] keys;
    delete[] C;
}

BNode *BNode::search(uint k){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n && k > keys[i]){
        i++;
    }
    if(keys[i] == k){
        return this;
    }
    if (leaf == true){
        return NULL;
    }
    return C[i]->search(k);
}

void BTree::insert(uint k){
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new BNode(B, true);
        root->keys[0] = k;
        root->n = 1;
    } 
    else{
        if (root->n == 2*B - 1){
            BNode *s = new BNode(B, false);
            s->C[0] = root;
            s->splitChild(0, root);
            int i = 0;
            if (s->keys[0] < k){
                i++;
            }
            s->C[i]->insertNonFull(k);
            root = s;
        } 
        else{
            root->insertNonFull(k);
        }
    }
}

void BNode::insertNonFull(uint k) {
    int i = n - 1;
    if (leaf == true) {
        while (i>=0 && keys[i] > k) {
            keys[i+1] = keys[i];
            i--;
        }
        keys[i+1] = k;
        n = n + 1;
    } 
    else {
        while (i>=0 && keys[i] > k){
            i--;
        }
        if (C[i+1]->n == 2*B-1) {
            splitChild(i+1, C[i+1]);
            if (keys[i + 1] < k){
                i++;
            }
        }
        C[i+1]->insertNonFull(k);
    }
}

void BNode::splitChild(int i, BNode *y) {
    BNode *z = new BNode(y->B, y->leaf);
    z->n = B - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < B - 1; j++){
        z->keys[j] = y->keys[j+B];
    }
    if (!y->leaf){
        for (int j = 0; j < B; j++)
        z->C[j] = y->C[j + B];
    }
    y->n = B - 1;
    for(int j=n; j >= i+1; j--){
        C[j+1] = C[j];
    }
    C[i + 1] = z;
    for (int j = n - 1; j >= i; j--){
        keys[j+1] = keys[j];
    }
    keys[i] = y->keys[B - 1];
    n = n + 1;
}

BTree::BTree(int temp){
    root = NULL;
    B = temp;
}

BTree::~BTree(){
    delete root;
}

BNode *BTree::search(uint k){
    return (root == NULL) ? NULL : root->search(k);
}

int BTree::search_bool(uint k){
    if(search(k) != NULL){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend not using `new` or `delete`.  Instead use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`.

Comment: First, I have not fully check your algorithm and what it does, I just look the code to check number of `new` and `delete` and the scope of each of those. So in method `insert`, you do `root = s;`, and base on the if-condition, the root is non-null, which means you are leaking what is inside `root` when assigning the `s`.  Also, I did not follow everything, but in `splitChild()`, the `BNode* z` is never delete too. You might need to iterate over your arrays to delete element inside.

Comment: @Vuwox I reached the same ideas (though `z` is always assigned so it's fine that it's not immediately destroyed in `splitChild`)

Comment: Yeah `z` is assign in array `C`, which should be iterated over in order to delete elements in it. BNode dtor is doing well to delete the allocated array itself, but no what is assigned inside of it.

Comment: Ah. Good point. Somehow I missed that glaring thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the simple diagnosis is that

```
delete[] C;
```

deletes only the array, not the nodes contained by it. So, (a) make sure they're properlu zero-initialized (b) delete them as well:

```
BNode** C    = new BNode* [2 * B] { 0 };

// in the destructor:
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * B; ++i)
    delete C[i];
delete[] C;
```

HOWEVER.

This doesn't work well because nodes can be split. After you moved some nodes from one node's C to another node's C, you run into double-free. So, when you split nodes, you have to make sure you set the moved-from C elemeent to NULL again:

```
            z->C[j] = y->C[j + B];
            y->C[j + B] = nullptr;
```

Now, this program runs clean under valgrind, ubsan and asan and without leaks:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b77fbb0361c63809)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using uint = unsigned;

class BNode {
  private:
    int     B;
    bool    leaf;
    uint*   keys = new uint[2 * B - 1]{0};
    BNode** C    = new BNode* [2 * B] { 0 };
    int     n    = 0;

  public:
    BNode(int t1, bool leaf1) : B(t1), leaf(leaf1) {}

    ~BNode()
    {
        delete[] keys;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * B; ++i)
            delete C[i];
        delete[] C;
    }

    BNode const* search(uint k) const
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n && k > keys[i]) {
            i++;
        }
        if (keys[i] == k) {
            return this;
        }
        return leaf ? nullptr : C[i]->search(k);
    }

    void insertNonFull(uint k)
    {
        int i = n - 1;
        if (leaf == true) {
            while (i >= 0 && keys[i] > k) {
                keys[i + 1] = keys[i];
                i--;
            }
            keys[i + 1] = k;
            n           = n + 1;
        } else {
            while (i >= 0 && keys[i] > k) {
                i--;
            }
            if (C[i + 1]->n == 2 * B - 1) {
                splitChild(i + 1, C[i + 1]);
                if (keys[i + 1] < k) {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            C[i + 1]->insertNonFull(k);
        }
    }

    void splitChild(int i, BNode* y)
    {
        BNode* z = new BNode(y->B, y->leaf);
        z->n     = B - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < B - 1; j++) {
            z->keys[j] = y->keys[j + B];
        }
        if (!y->leaf) {
            for (int j = 0; j < B; j++) {
                z->C[j]     = y->C[j + B];
                y->C[j + B] = nullptr;
            }
        }
        y->n = B - 1;
        for (int j = n; j >= i + 1; j--) {
            C[j + 1] = C[j];
        }
        C[i + 1] = z;
        for (int j = n - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            keys[j + 1] = keys[j];
        }
        keys[i] = y->keys[B - 1];
        n       = n + 1;
    }

    friend class BTree;
};

class BTree {
  private:
    BNode* root = nullptr;
    int    B;

  public:
    BTree(int temp)
    {
        root = nullptr;
        B    = temp;
    }

    ~BTree() { delete root; }

    BNode const* search(uint k) const
    {
        return (root == nullptr) ? nullptr : root->search(k);
    }

    bool search_bool(uint k) const { return search(k) != nullptr; }

    void insert(uint k)
    {
        if (!root) {
            root          = new BNode(B, true);
            root->keys[0] = k;
            root->n       = 1;
        } else {
            if (root->n == 2 * B - 1) {
                BNode* s = new BNode(B, false);
                s->C[0]  = root;
                s->splitChild(0, root);
                int i = 0;
                if (s->keys[0] < k) {
                    i++;
                }
                s->C[i]->insertNonFull(k);
                root = s;
            } else {
                root->insertNonFull(k);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    for (int b = 8; b < 17; ++b) {
        BTree tree(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100'000; ++i)
            tree.insert(rand() % 1000);
    }
}
```

### In Closing

Kudos for getting the algorithmics largely right here. That's not easy.

As you can see in my cleanup/review I hardened a lot of stuff, mainly around initialization. This is an important habit. I can't actually rule out that not having that would have exposed other sleeping bugs.

Also note the increased const-correctness.

Also, like other said, prefer smart pointers and modern C++ techniques. It will be amazing how much less error prone just using `std::array`, `unique_ptr` and so will be. For example, the bug with moving nodes in `splitChild` would never have compiled because you **have to** explcitly move-assign `unique_ptr`

### Bonus

Example in more modern C++:

- without any new/delete
- without any raw pointer
- no more manual destructors (even no constructors required, really)
- compiler checked move semantics, NICE!
- statically known B factor, so everything becomes 10x more performant, while still being tunable
- generic key (element) type, so you can now store `std::string`, `double`, whatnot
- generic comparator, so you sort your keys in alternative orders (e.g. `Btree<std::string, 16, std::greater<> >` to store the keys in descending order instead of ascending).
- No leaks!

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f03fa060e98affd)**

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, unsigned B = 16, typename Cmp = std::less<T>>
class BTree {
  private:
    static constexpr unsigned MaxKeys     = 2 * B - 1;
    static constexpr unsigned MaxChildren = 2 * B;

    struct BNode;
    using NodePtr = std::unique_ptr<BNode>;

    struct BNode {
        bool _leaf;
        int  _n = 0;

        std::array<T, MaxKeys>           _keys{};
        std::array<NodePtr, MaxChildren> _children{};

        BNode(bool leaf1) : _leaf(leaf1) {}

        BNode const* search(T k, Cmp cmp) const
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < _n && cmp(_keys[i], k)) {
                i++;
            }
            if (_keys[i] == k) {
                return this;
            }
            return _leaf ? nullptr : _children[i]->search(k, cmp);
        }

        void insertNonFull(T k, Cmp cmp)
        {
            int i = _n - 1;
            if (_leaf == true) {
                while (i >= 0 && cmp(k, _keys[i])) {
                    _keys[i + 1] = _keys[i];
                    i--;
                }
                _keys[i + 1] = k;
                _n           = _n + 1;
            } else {
                while (i >= 0 && cmp(k, _keys[i])) {
                    i--;
                }
                if (_children[i + 1]->_n == MaxKeys) {
                    splitChild(i + 1, *_children[i + 1]);
                    if (cmp(_keys[i + 1], k)) {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                _children[i + 1]->insertNonFull(k, cmp);
            }
        }

        void splitChild(int i, BNode& y)
        {
            NodePtr z = std::make_unique<BNode>(y._leaf);
            z->_n     = B - 1;
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < B - 1; j++) {
                z->_keys[j] = y._keys[j + B];
            }
            if (!y._leaf) {
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < B; j++) {
                    z->_children[j] = std::move(y._children[j + B]);
                }
            }
            y._n = B - 1;
            for (int j = _n; j >= i + 1; j--) {
                _children[j + 1] = std::move(_children[j]);
            }
            _children[i + 1] = std::move(z);
            for (int j = _n - 1; j >= i; j--) {
                _keys[j + 1] = _keys[j];
            }
            _keys[i] = y._keys[B - 1];
            _n       = _n + 1;
        }
    };

    NodePtr root = nullptr;
    Cmp     _cmp{};

  public:
    BTree(Cmp cmp = {}) : _cmp(std::move(cmp)) {}

    BNode const* search(T k) const {
        return root ? root->search(k, _cmp) : nullptr;
    }

    bool search_bool(T k) const { return search(k) != nullptr; }

    void insert(T k)
    {
        if (!root) {
            root           = std::make_unique<BNode>(true);
            root->_keys[0] = k;
            root->_n       = 1;
        } else {
            if (root->_n == MaxKeys) {
                NodePtr s       = std::make_unique<BNode>(false);
                s->splitChild(0, *root);
                s->_children[0] = std::move(root);
                int i = 0;
                if (_cmp(s->_keys[0], k)) {
                    i++;
                }
                s->_children[i]->insertNonFull(k, _cmp);
                root = std::move(s);
            } else {
                root->insertNonFull(k, _cmp);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    using Asc  = std::less<>;
    using Desc = std::greater<>;
    BTree<double,   8,  Asc>  b8;
    BTree<int,      9,  Desc> b9;
    BTree<unsigned, 10, Asc>  b10;
    BTree<size_t,   11, Desc> b11;
    BTree<double,   12, Asc>  b12;
    BTree<int,      13, Desc> b13;
    BTree<unsigned, 14, Asc>  b14;
    BTree<size_t,   15, Desc> b15;
    BTree<int,      16> b16; // default is ascending

    for (int i = 0; i < 100'000; ++i) {
        b8.insert(rand() % 10000);
        b9.insert(rand() % 10000);
        b10.insert(rand() % 10000);
        b11.insert(rand() % 10000);
        b12.insert(rand() % 10000);
        b13.insert(rand() % 10000);
        b14.insert(rand() % 10000);
        b15.insert(rand() % 10000);
        b16.insert(rand() % 10000);
    }

    {
        struct NC {
            int v;
            bool operator==(NC const& o) const { return v == o.v; }
        };
        struct CMP {
            bool operator()(NC const& a, NC const& b) const { return a.v < b.v; }
        };

        BTree<NC, 8, CMP> b8;
        b8.insert({42});
        bool ok = b8.search_bool({42});
    }
}
```

Comment: Added a bonus take using more modern C++ (no new/delete, for starters) **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33c81517fc9ed1f6)** (/cc @vuwox cheers for hooking me on this question :))

Comment: Missed a spot, now also exercise the `search` method ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f03fa060e98affd))

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed answer! It managed to run without issues with your fixes, and I could apply them to my other failing structures as well. I think I have to learn to deal with unique_ptr, it would have done everything easier! Thanks a lot!